# Java (WAR file) obfuscation tool

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

We have a large enterprise web project that uses;

- JDK 1.7
- JSF & Primefaces
- Spring Framework MVC 3.1.1
- Several Web Service clients
- Annotations (for spring rest services)

We want to obfuscate the builded WAR file before deploying it on the customer's side.
I have read several of tutorials and tried Proguard and JShrink but failed.

Proguard gives several warnings such as: 
**"Warning: class [WEB-INF/classes/web/util/XMLGregorianCalendarSerializer.class] unexpectedly contains class [web.util.XMLGregorianCalendarSerializer]"**

and

**Warning: there were 282 classes in incorrectly named files.**

Note that I am using NetBeans IDE 7.2.1 any plug in for it are also welcome.

Any good tutorials or anyone can lead me?

Comment: Why don't you just simply place pc locking code everywhere that simply checks the MD5 of it's own file?
If md5 changes means user has tried to fiddle with it == removal of all .java files on clients computer, removal of all .class files, removal of all .jar files and removal of all .war files... and a locked computer, and a message that the developer has been notified of breach of contract and the fine of $xxxxx will be issued shortly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obfuscating WAR file with Proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690812/obfuscating-war-file-with-proguard)