# Java war obfuscation

Tags: java, war, obfuscation

I wish to obfuscate my java based ant and maven war deployments .

**Currently my process is:** 
I will generate a war out of the java source code using ant/maven and deploy that war file to the server.

**Note:**
My java application is not having the main class.

I have tried yguard . 
It compress all the class file in to a jar named `webapp.jar`. on decoding that jar file , gives all the java files . That was not obfuscated.

Reference link : http://codeaweso.me/2009/02/obfuscating-a-webapp-war-file-with-yguard-and-ant/

Can any one help me to do the obsfucation for the above case?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690812/obfuscating-war-file-with-proguard) question and its answer.

Comment: You want us to read a web site and apply it for you?

Comment: Of course it would give java files. Obfuscation makes the code harder to understand, it doesn't make it unreadable because that code still needs to be executed. Maybe you want encryption instead?

Comment: Then this yguard obfuscation will not be useful to hide the code in client side deployment even on reverse enginering ( using jad)?